# How to handle 3 multiple logins from url?

Tags: java, android

I am making app which is related doctor and sales.

I have 3 login from 
see..

http://192.168.3.222/ZHPLPortal/WebServices/Login_WebService.asmx/LoginDetail?UserName=admin&Password=admin100
in here admin and password
==>   anyone can do anything

and second url

http://192.168.3.222/ZHPLPortal/WebServices/Login_WebService.asmx/LoginDetail?UserName=dm-nagpur&Password=dm-nagpur
I want to open diffrent activity or fragment.
So how can i?

I want to know that how to store different login username and password
and open any activity.

Like I have one login for example:

```
username:admin
password:admin100
```

Then first open mydrawer.class
Mydrawer menu we have like dashboard ,dailyplanner,doctor_list,activity,pob,stockist.
And when I click dailyplanner so that activity is date.zava okk

When I switch another login so when
I click again same dailyplanner it should open data.java.

Comment: you may try using shared preferences to store multiple user logins

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think there are two type of login in your admin and user.So i think you need to open different activity for both admin and user.

To achieve this just add **role** in database when admin logs in in response send **role** as "admin" and based on role you can open particular activity and for use set **role** as "user"

So when ever login authentication done get role from database and sent it in response.

Answer (score 0):

U can manage it by using user role, You will get the object of user with his role, with the help of this you can verify which user had login in your app. And you can easily redirect to the user to his respective Activity.

I hope you will get your answer for any query please revert me back.

Comment: Please mark right if it helped you, and you have got your answer